# Display of error message despite radio selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is a radio button for category, which if not selected then, error message must get displayed. But, the problem is that, error message gets displayed, even after selecting a category.

```js
$scope.save_data = function () {
  var scope = angular.element('#outer').scope();
  if ($scope.request_type_out == '' || $scope.request_type_out == undefined) {
    console.log('category empty or undefined');
    $("#category_id").addClass("error");
  } else {
    $("#category_id").removeClass("error");
    scope.dm.request_type_out = $scope.request_type_out;
    scope.completeActivity();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide you html code of angular component .

Comment: will you please add code in codepen or in js fiddle etc

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout the code in my  [stackblitz link](https://angular-playground.stackblitz.io)

**HTML CODE**

```
<select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
    <option >---</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
    <h2 *ngIf="!flag">{{errorMessage}}</h2>
```

**.ts File**

```
  flag:Boolean = false;
    errorMessage = "Please select the value from dropdown";
onChange(event){
    console.log(event);
    this.flag = true;
}
```

Checkout the answer .